# starting existing android activity

Tags: android, android-intent

hi i have an application
A is launcher activity from that i create B activity. From B i want to go back to A without deleting the instance of B(so no finish) then i want to create a new instance of B lets call it B2. And from A i want to be able to show B or B2 without recreating them.
again i stress that B,B2 are the same class just diffrent instances.

from B when i want to go to A i thought of using

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainAct.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

but i think that its a mistake because it will clear other instances.
what intent must i use in the cases?
in c# windows application we would do B.hide();A.show(). then from A we could do
A.hide(); B.SHOW() or B1.show();
how can i do that in android please?

Comment: Your design is flawed.  You should not attempt to create 2 instances of the same Activity.  Instead, use intent extras (or some other mechanism) to pass the data to be displayed to the instance.  c# (Windows) and Android are very different beasts.

Comment: i would like to provide some information . its a chat application. so A is the main activity, B,B1 are the chatrooms. obviously i want the user to be able to switch chatrooms. so user is in A then goes into chatroom B. then i want him to return to A go to B1  but without closing B so he can return later. cant this be done?

Comment: So... Why couldn't you use the same activity to display different chat windows?  Seems like you would just say "_switch to this conversation_" which would mean switching the data that is gets displayed.

Comment: If I were building this, the chat room would be a list view bound to an adapter which is the history of the chats.  I would pass the appropriate adapter to use to the Activity when I started it.  There may be better approaches.  This is good OOP.  The Activity has no idea what a chat room is.  It simply displays, and interacts with, the data it's told to use.

Comment: so you are proposing having an array of datasources for all the information of the diffrent chat rooms and therefore try to switch between thenm each time?when i say datasources i mean the lists/adapters etc?

Comment: Activities are managed by the system. You should not be creating and storing instances of them yourself and trying to show them. Please reconsider your design

Comment: The [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is an important concept to understand.  The system manages the lifecycle of your Activities.  You need to accept this idea and design your app accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `B` is an Activity, you can't have two different instances of it.

You can have 2 different Activities that extend the same class, but you've indicated you don't want that.

You need to find a way to change the appearance and behavior of `B` rather than creating a new instance.

Please consider reading about the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

from the doc

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's
>   history stack if it is already running.

Comment: i have A as  android:launchMode="singleTask". the flag you mention works for B going to A (it doesnt go through the create).But it doesnt work for the A going back to the B. it starts a new activity and goes through the create. i have B,B1 in a arraylist of activities and therefore i would like to select one and open it

Comment: @user1855793 - It sounds like you're really trying to fight against the Activity Lifecycle.  Seems like a really bad idea.